# How to understand escaping in this SQL query embedded in Java Script

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

```
var queryString="select replace(B.entity, '''','\\\''') from B"
```

I am assuming the next line will fire this query at an Oracle data source.

I think it says replace in the raw data response any apostrophe character with backslash-apsotrophe.

Is that right?

but I'm still trying to understand why it is this way.  The second parameter is simply escaping putting two apostrophes together as an Oracle way of escaping an apostrophe.  But what about the third parameter?  Why are THREE backslashes necessary?  Why wouldn't it be `'\\'''`

Comment: This is not Oracle PL/SQL related but plain SQL. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will replace a single quote with three backslashes then a quote.

to check this I did

`select replace('''blah''', '''','\\\''') from dual;`

this returns

\\\'blah\\\'

Comment: What is the value of B.entity in your example?

Comment: b.entity is just a field from a table so I replaced it with the text '''blah'''.